# How do I know whether the addons I've installed are compatible with electrolysis in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Firefox has added electrolysis for multiprocess support, but the presence of an addon that does not support it will disable electrolysis. How do I know whether the addons I installed are compatible with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I know whether the addons I installed are compatible?

Use the Add-on Compatibility Reporter:

> Probably the best way to test if your add-ons work with e10s is to use the [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) which will tell you if your add-ons are multi-process compatible and let you tell the developer how well they work. See this [blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/09/07/help-make-add-ons-multiprocess-compatible-with-add-on-compatibility-reporter/) for more.

Source [Are we e10s yet?](https://arewee10syet.com/)

---

#### Add-on Compatibility Reporter

> After installing the ACR, you can report if the Firefox add-ons that
> you're using are working properly. If you notice that one of your
> add-ons doesn't seem to be working the same way it did in previous
> versions of the application, just open the Add-ons Manager and click
> 'Report Issue' next to that add-on to send a report to Mozilla.
>
> Three weeks after a Firefox version bump, we will be prompting users
> using Aurora/Beta for information about whether their add-ons work.
> This will be a popup panel. The panel can manually be initiated by
> clicking the add-on icon in the Add-ons Bar.
>
> Even if your add-ons all work fine, if they're marked incompatible,
> please let us know that they work fine by submitting a success report
> so we can encourage the add-on developer to update their compatibility
> information.
>
> We'll collect all of the reports and let add-on developers know what
> users are having problems with, or if their add-ons seem to work just
> fine in future versions of the product.
>
> [image]

Source [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/)

---

#### Help make add-ons multiprocess compatible with Add-on Compatibility Reporter

> Firefox is currently transitioning to a multiprocess architecture
> (e10s), which will give users a more stable and responsive browser.
> This transition affects certain add-ons, which must adapt to the new
> model or they won’t work correctly, and will be flagged as
> incompatible. We’re reaching out to add-on developers in various ways
> so they can check whether their add-ons are affected, and get support
> for updating their add-ons.
>
> Now, there’s a way for you to help as well with outreach efforts, and
> that is by reporting incompatible add-ons.
>
> Add-on Compatibility Reporter (ACR) enables you to tell us if an
> add-on works in a particular version of Firefox. Its reports have been
> a very useful tool for us in tracking incompatible add-ons and helping
> developers fix them. Add-on developers are also able to see reports
> sent for their add-ons in the developer tools. If you want to give it
> a try, we suggest that you do on one of the prerelease versions: Beta,
> Developer Edition, or Nightly. The latter two have multiprocess
> enabled for all add-ons by default, which is what we’re most
> interested in at the moment.
>
> The latest versions of ACR have integrated support for multiprocess
> Firefox. Once you install the add-on, you will see which of your
> add-ons have declared multiprocess compatibility. You will also see if
> your version of Firefox has multiprocess enabled. The icons let you
> report if an add-on works or not.
>
> [image]

Source [Help make add-ons multiprocess compatible with Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/09/07/help-make-add-ons-multiprocess-compatible-with-add-on-compatibility-reporter/)

Notes:

- This add-on was removed by the author. There is a copy available at https://web.archive.org/web/20170831184231/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/versions/.
- It is not compatible with the current version of Firefox (59.0.2)

Comment: Unfortunately, the ACR add-on is no longer available

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20170831184231/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/versions/

Comment: @Lizz Answer updated.